# Asp razor page return 400 code when POST form from Iframe

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to post a form from an Iframe. But I am getting 400 error and I don't know why. In the iframe it shows the GET requests and I also set `"X-Frame-Options", "ALLOW-FROM ...` in the GET and POST method headers.

Here is the request:

```
Host: localhost:52136
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:52136/
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 796
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

And the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Kestrel
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcR2VydmlsIERvdWJhbFxzb3VyY2VccmVwb3NcQWNvbXBhIGNoYXJ0XE9ubGluZUFnZW5jeQ==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 18 Dec 2018 20:41:55 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

When I submit the same form directly from the same url in the browser, I dont get any error.

How to fix it in the iframe?

Comment: This sounds like it could be a CSRF mitigation issue.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: The first thing to do is confirm whether or not that is the issue. You can **temporarily** disable the CSRF check using the suggestion [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7012#issuecomment-342908836).

Comment: I just set [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)] to my pageModel and it redirected fine. But I used to store some data in the tempdata. But After the redirection the tempdata does not have any data like it does when submitting the form directly.

Comment: I don't know the specific details of how it works with iframes, but it seems that cookies aren't being sent when you make the request from inside of your iframe. Hopefully that gives you something to look into at least.

Comment: Ok. I will focus on that tempdata later. What to do about the CSRF mitigation issue? because I cannot let the AntiforgeryToken disabled for security things.

Comment: It will all be part of the same issue. Both the CSRF protection and the TempData feature use cookies.

Comment: Also, I just set data to the cookie in the post action and get it back after the redirection. It's just tempdata looks different than the cookie.

Comment: After some test, I can see that cookie works in IFrames but not session.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I encountered same error while using a Asp.net core app (Razor Pages) in Iframe of SharePoint Online site.

Solution:

Add following configuration in Startup.cs file of your asp.net core app. 
(you may have to add a reference of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc)

**Step 1**

Enable [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) to add Parent URL to trusted CORS domains.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>    
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors https://mysharepointparentsite.sharepoint.com/");
        await next();
    });
}
```

**Step 2**
Enable [Ignore Anti Forgery Token](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7012) validation.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(_options =>
    {
        _options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you need to check whether you have not done code for CSRF prevention like below:

options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute()); in startup file().

This spent 5 hours to find as I tried with JSONP, CORS, and CSRF.